# Ramos W16 Android Usb driver

Tags: android, usb, tablet

Have an issue with my Ramos W16. Upgraded to the last firmware. Now I want to root device, but can't install drivers.
Here is hardware Id's
USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E22&REV_0231
USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E22

OS: Windows 7 x64. In Device management tablet is visible as USB Composite Device.
I've tried a bunch of different drivers, but they don't work. Somebody help me! Tried USBDeview - deleted all drivers.

Comment: Is this a development question or more in the spirit of rooting? If so, this is the wrong forum for this.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com